# Microsoft Certification - 70-764 Administering a SQL Database Infrastructure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, learning

Firstly, I apologise if this is not necessarily the best place to post such a question.

I am currently preparing for my 70-764 exam. I have purchased the following book:

[70-764](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-764-administering-a-sql-database-infrastructure-9781509303830)

I have a few questions regarding the book and its resources:

1. Previously, I have purchased other Microsoft Certification books and have normally got a PDF version, along with the printed book. Is this not the case anymore? Am I missing a disk or something?
2. The book has many URLS for supporting resources, however, these dont appear to be valid any longer. For example, early on within the book, there is a URL given for a list of useful links which accompany the book, I cannot find these online at all.
3. Practice tests also used to come with the book, however this does not appear to be the case any longer. Is this by design? Or am I just missing something here?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Q1: Previously, I have purchased other Microsoft Certification books and have normally got a PDF version, along with the printed book. Is this not the case anymore? Am I missing a disk or something?*

On the page you linked to, there were 3 options: book, ebook, and book + ebook. You would need to buy the book + ebook option if you wanted both.

*Q2: The book has many URLS for supporting resources, however, these don't appear to be valid any longer. For example, early on within the book, there is a URL given for a list of useful links which accompany the book, I cannot find these online at all.*

Yeah, typical problem with dead tree printed versions of the internet: the links are often out of date. You can try using the [Wayback Machine at archive.org](https://archive.org/) to see if they've been archived.

*Q3: Practice tests also used to come with the book, however this does not appear to be the case any longer. Is this by design? Or am I just missing something here?*

On the page you linked to, it says, "This title is also available [for sale with a practice test](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-764-administering-a-sql-database-infrastructure-9781509305759)." You would want to click that link and buy the other version with the practice test if that's important to you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had seen those options on the page, I just thought I may have been entitled to a free PDF version, since I purchased the book (as per previous certification book purchases). I guess i just need to purchase the PDF then.

Great tip about the Wayback Machine, i had totally forgot about that. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Your question does not relate to database administration, but answering to your question:
when buying books from microsoft press, you can select what option to purchase (printed book / ebook / printed + ebook). The prices are different.
There is also a downloads section with code examples. 
In case of any problems with your purchase - you should contact the seller directly.

Here's the link for [Exam Ref 70-764](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-764-administering-a-sql-database-infrastructure-9781509303830)

Comment: Anyone perusing DBA would probably have this question regarding materials for DBA exams. It would stand to reason that it does relate to DBA, yes?